# Как с помощью jQuery получить данные в элементе SPAN?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть код:

```
<span class="word" data-wv="Able">
    Able
</span>

<span class="word" data-wv="apple">
    apple
</span>

<span class="word" data-wv="and">
    and
</span>
```

Как при нажатии на одно из слов передать его значение data-wv в get запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('span').click(function() {
  var e = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: "GET",
    data: {wv: $(e).attr('data-wv')}, // или $(e).data('wv'), или $(e).data().wv
    success: function() {
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, благодарю, подправил)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А success это ответ от сервера?

Comment: @RomanKravets, да

Comment: @Yuri тоесть в success я пишу что должно выполниться после получения ответа? (у меня на сервере есть return newWord )

Comment: @RomanKravets, да. Есть ещё что должно выполняться до ответа и если запрос вернул ошибку